# Logstash multiline codec ignore last event / line

Tags: logstash, multiline, logstash-configuration

Logstash multiline codec ignore my last event (line) until send next package of logs.

My logstash.conf:

```
input {
    }
    http {
        port => "5001"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\]"
            negate => true
            what => previous
            auto_flush_interval => 15
        }
    }
}

filter{
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "(?m)\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]\s\<%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}\>\s\[%{WORD:component}\]\s%{GREEDYDATA:log-message}" 
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        index => "%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
    }
}
```

Moreover solution with **auto_flush_interval** don't work.

**For example:**

**input** using Postman:

> [2017-07-11 22:32:12.345]  [KCU] Component initializing
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
>   [2017-07-11 22:32:16.345]  [KCU] Return with status 1

**output** - only one event (should be two):

> [2017-07-11 22:32:12.345]  [KCU] Component initializing
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)

I need this last line.

**Question:**
Am I doing something wrong or there are problems with multiline codec? - How to fix this?

Comment: Did my answer help to solve your question?

Comment: This same question did get an answer here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-multiline-codec-ignore-last-event-line/109006

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're using the multiline codec wrong. Let's take a look at your configuration:

```
codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}\]"
            negate => true
            what => previous
        }
```

It says if a logline does not (`negate => true`) start with a ISO timestamp (`pattern`) append it to the previous log line (`what => previous`).

But the logline you're missing starts with a ISO timestamp:

> [2017-07-11 22:32:16.345] [KCU] Return with status 1

So it will not be appended to the previous log lines but instead create a new document in Elasticsearch.